# What is the difference between "active listening" and the "sender-receiver model"?

Tags: communication, pmp, pmbok, pmi-framework, communication-management

I don't quite understand the difference between active listening and the sender-receiver model.

**active listening:** The message receiver restates what’s been said to fully understand and confirm  the message and it provides an opportunity for the sender to clarify the  message if needed.

**sender-receiver model:** Communication requires a sender and a receiver. Within this model may be  multiple avenues to complete the flow of communication, but barriers to effective communication may be present as well.

Can someone please explain the differences to me?

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with project management. Wouldn't this be more on-topic [on IPS](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

PMP uses the [sender-receiver model](https://www.dummies.com/careers/project-management/pmp-certification/plan-communications-management-tools-you-should-know-for-the-pmp-certification-exam/#tab3) of communication in which parties alternate their roles to keep the communication going.

[image]

So it's an interactive model of communication, with feedback incorporated, as opposed to a unidirectional approach (like the radio for example, where the sender just blasts information at the receiver, which isn't really communication, just transmission).

Active listening is just a way to confirm that the message is being not just received but understood, and it's exactly what the name says, the receiver of the message [confirms that the message is being received through feedback, questions, prompts for clarity, and other signs of confirmation](https://www.pmi.org/learning/library/effective-communication-better-project-management-6480) which show that they are participating actively, not just being there with sound entering their ears while they are catching up on emails or something.

Active listening is a factor (in verbal communication) that influences how the communication occurs in the sender-receiver model.